# Django not load sencha index.html

Tags: django, extjs

I am trying to run an ExtJS 7 app using and django 3 as backend.
The same index.html created by sencha cmd loads and runs as expected. 
But loading it with django backend it does not load and gives an error (described  below).

I guesss it is related to csrf token.

index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>front</title>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
   <script id="microloader"
            data-app="eef86001-0c1f-47f8-bad2-962464cb0916" 
            type="text/javascript" src="{%static "bootstrap.js" %}"  >

   </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html
```

Error in chrome:

```
bootstrap.js:868 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/bootstrap.json?_dc=1576345210630 404 (Not Found)
VM52:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at new Manifest (bootstrap.js:1949)
    at Object.setManifest (bootstrap.js:2161)
    at bootstrap.js:2141
    at XMLHttpRequest.readyStateChange (bootstrap.js:854)
```

Thank you all for any help
Koby Peleg Hen

​

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load `index.html` and `bootstrap.json` from two different locations.

Make sure `bootstrap.json is located` in `127.0.0.1/index/` with `port 8000`.

The `index.html` is loaded correct.

Comment: No , the index that you see came from the following ...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/',views.index)
]
The index.html it self load the bootstartp.js >> bootstrap.json

Comment: Right, but the error says, that bootstrap.js could not be loaded. This is loaded from the index.html --> index.html is loaded, but seems to be in a different location than bootstrap.

Comment: They are at the save location.
the error say :  Unexpected token which I think related to something with CSRF token from the django side which I not manage to find.

Comment: I must said that the index.html is loading perfectly if I just load it from the browser
directly. (with no backend)
To reproduce that you can down load sencha Extjs Open Source edition and try it out.

Comment: Do you have a link to your Django server?

Comment: the server is in development lab , Not avail on the web.
But if you want to repreduce the error I can guide you

Comment: Both Sencha and Django are Open Source Project